# Is it possible to access ignored elements in AppleScript and System Events?

Tags: xcode, scripting, applescript, accessibility, juce

I often use AppleScript with System Events to access various UI elements in a program's window such as this script:

```
tell application "System Events"

if exists (process "Pro Tools") then
    
    tell process "Pro Tools"
        
        set frontmost to true
        
        if exists (window pluginTitle) then
            click button "Analyze" of window pluginTitle
        else
            click menu item connectVersion of menu of menu item "Noise Reduction" of menu "Audiosuite" of menu bar 1
            click button "Analyze" of window pluginTitle
        end if
        
    end tell
    
else
    
    return
    
end if

end tell
```

I've recently come across some windows where I can't access the UI element.  I use Accessibility Inspector and UI Browser to help me find these elements.  Accessibility Inspector, which comes installed with Xcode, can actually find certain elements that UI Browser can't.  If you turn on "Show Ignored Elements" in the "Inspection" menu, it will show you the full path.

[image: Show Ignored Elements]

[image]

I assume there is no way to access these elements in AppleScript, but would be very grateful if anyone knows why they are referred to as ignored and what could the developer do to fix it.

Comment: Looking at UI stuff that I have created, those look like containers such as a NSView, NSBox, etc.